# Loading data into Data Table

Tags: javascript, php, json, datatable

I am fetching data from database in array and then converting it to json object to pass the data to data table but data is not showing in table whereas on console data is showing. I am new to Data Table plugin cant figure it out where i am doing wrong.
Any help?

Here is my Code

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="90%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DESIGNATION</th>
            <th>EMP_FIRST_NAME</th>
            <th>EMP_MIDDLE_NAME</th>
            <th>EMP_LAST_NAME</th>
            <th>HOME_ADDRESS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
        $.ajax({
        url: "test2.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,

            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
                assignToEventsColumns(data);
            }
    });


    function assignToEventsColumns(data) {
        var table = $('#example').dataTable({
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "columns": [{
                "mData": "DESIGNATION"
            }, {
                "mData": "EMP_FIRST_NAME"
            }, {
                "mData": "EMP_MIDDLE_NAME"
            }, {
                "mData": "EMP_LAST_NAME"
            }, {
                "mData": "HOME_ADDRESS"
            }]
        })
    }

</script>
```

This is my back end code:

```
function recordSetToJson($resultSet){
$rs = array();
while($rs[] = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet)) {
    // you don´t really need to do anything here.
}
//return json_encode($rs);
return $rs;}

function getFormListForHR($client_Id,$pageNo,$pageSize) {
    $dbcon = new portlet_connect();
    $conn = $dbcon->getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, ROWNUM r__
            FROM (SELECT * FROM FORM_MAIN_MEMBER WHERE USER_ID in (select USER_ID from PORTLETS_USERS Where CLIENT_ID = '$client_Id') ORDER BY FORM_ID DESC ) a
            WHERE ROWNUM < ( ($pageNo * $pageSize) + 1))
            WHERE r__ >= ( ( ($pageNo-1) * $pageSize) + 1) ";
    $HRForms = recordSetToJson(odbc_exec($conn, $sql));
    odbc_close($conn);

    $jsonData = json_encode(array('MembersList' => $HRForms), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);;
    return $jsonData;}

echo getFormListForHR($client_Id,$pageNo,$pageSize);
```

Comment: Please avoid using screenshots as much as possible.  When providing text, do so with copy-paste then format it as needed.  Volunteers will not find yourr question attractive if they have to manually type out your sample data to begin testing their code and Google will have a hard time linking this page to future Google search queries.

Comment: @mickmackusa i'll take care in future. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome to take care right now.  Questions can be edited.